# How come geom_hline and geom_text behave differently in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using `geom_text` without `aes` will render a text multiple times (actually, `nrow(iris)` times):

```
ggplot(iris) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width)) +
  geom_text(label='afasd', x=1, y=0.5)
```

In fact, this is how most `geom_xxx` layer function works, unless a `data` parameter is specified. However, `geom_hline` doesn't behave quite the same:

```
ggplot(iris) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=1)
```

This draws the `hline` only once.

Is it supposed to be this way, or is it a mistake?

Comment: They don't.  You are using them differently. You are not mapping the data to `geom_hline()`, instead specifying only a single value.  Had you used `geom_hline(aes(yintercept = Petal.Width)` you would get multiple hlines.

Comment: @Andrie: Thanks. But notice that I didn't use `aes` in the first example as well.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I think the anomaly is `geom_text`, not `geom_hline`.  To fix this anomaly, use `annotate()` instead of `geom_text()`

Comment: @Andrie: Thanks. I'm aware of `annotate` and in fact the lacking of `hline` in `annotate` inspired this question. But other `geom`'s like `geom_point` behave the same as `geom_text`. Try `geom_point(x=1,y=1)`.